# How to know the module coding well , good quality?

Tags: module, third-party-module

This question is from the store owner point of view without any coding knowledge

When I want to purchase a paid module, for example, 'one step checkout', I found there are a LOT of similar module

Popular module have similar feature, service (support, update) and some good reviews

Usually, there are few issue and I have to get support and it finally works well.

but while I'm using many modules for our store, I have no idea it's made well, good quality module and I can't judge I'm using right, correct module

**How to know the module is code well or have good quality?**

(Btw, what is the exact meaning 'coding well' or necessary point to be good module?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a webservice for this, at least that i know. It was created by Allan MacGregor and it is called http://triplecheck.io/ where you can see the coding standards of a module. I think it only works for free modules anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Check the amount of module updates, this is a good indication if it is activily developed. Check the developers website and any other modules they have developed and their comments. Some developers have good feedback and good support, this is usually mentioned in comments. Also, the amount of time a developer has been developing for.

Generally speaking though, you can't really judge a module until you see the code for yourself.

Comment: Check the amount of module updates is good point. but I wish I can find something more detail while I'm using if I choose right one or not

Comment: 'the amount of module updates' is not a good/or bad indicator of a module. 
If a module is well written/existed for a good couple of years, and feature rich/complete, you'd not see many updates. This is a good thing.
If a module is new, and not yet feature rich you'd see the opposite, again this is a good thing. It shows commitment from the developer(s) to make the module stable/feature rich/complete